# How to bind submit once per ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing an angular-node.js application as a cloud plugin for jira where I have a button which when clicked triggers a post request. I am facing a strange issue where this post request is getting called the number of times the button is clicked. For example if I click button for first time - post request is called once, if I click again that is the second time post request executes twice and so on. Once I refresh the page it starts form zero again. Here is the code:

controller code:

```
$scope.addActor = function(){
    AP.require('dialog', function(dialog){
        dialog.create({
            key: 'actor-content',
            width: '40%',
            height: '30%',
            chrome: true,
        });
    });

    AP.require('events', function(events){
        events.on('customEvent', function(){
            console.log(arguments[0]);
            var data = {
                productName: $scope.productName,
                checked: false,
                actor: arguments[0]
            };

            $http.post('/addActor', data)
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.actors = [];

                    for (var actor in data){

                        console.log(data[actor].checked)
                        console.log(data[actor].actor)

                        $scope.actors.push({
                            checked : data[actor].checked,
                            id : data[actor].actor
                        });
                    }

                    AP.require("messages", function(messages){
                        //create a message
                        var message = messages.success('','Actor added');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            messages.clear(message);
                        }, 2000);
                    });


                    /*$scope.formData = {};*/

                }).error(function(data){
                    AP.require("messages", function(messages){
                        //create a message
                        var message = messages.error('','Error in Adding Actor');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            messages.clear(message);
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
        });
    });

};
```

dialogActor.hbs

```
<body style="background:white">

        <div class="aui-dialog2-content">
            <script>


                $(document).one('click', function(e) {
                    // initialization here

                    AP.require('dialog', function(dialog) {
                        dialog.getButton('submit').bind(function() {

                            AP.require('events', function(events){
                                var actor = $('#actor').val();
                                events.emit('customEvent', actor);
                            });

                            dialog.close();
                        });
                        dialog.getButton('cancel').bind(function () {
                            dialog.close();
                        });
                    });
                });

            </script>

            <form class="aui" action="#" name="jiraform" id="actorform">


                <div class="content">
                    <div class="field-group">

                        <label for="summary">Actor<span class="aui-icon icon-required">Required</span></label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="actor" id="actor" class="text long-field" data-aui-validation-field data-aui-validation-required="required" required>
                        <span class="actorError" style="color: #880000"></span>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: how are you identifying the request is being made multiple times, from the network tab or from the console.log() ???

Answer (score 0):

Changing from

```
AP.require('events', function(events){
        events.on('customEvent', function(){
    })
})


AP.require('events', function(events){
            events.once('customEvent', function(){
        })
    })
```

solved the problem. This makes sure that the event is occuring once.